# k-fold cross validation: Force at least m instances in each fold

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation, glmnet

I'm dealing with a multi-output regression problem (~ 800 dependent variables, ~ 1300 observations). My current approach is to train a single model for each output. To select an "optimal" lambda I tried to use cv.glmnet, but the training fails as some targets occured only a few (e. g. 2-5) times in the past (the other instances are 0 for this  target). If this is the case, I need to force these instances to be present in each fold (some kind of stratified sampling). Otherwise there's a high probability that there's no variation in y and cv.glmnet produces following error message:

> Error in elnet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, type.gaussian, : y is constant; gaussian glmnet fails at standardization step.

How can I make sure / control that those observations are in each fold if the number of instances for a specific target is small?

Answer (score 1):

If i have understand your problem statement, then Stratified sampling can help you tuning the hyperparameter(lambda).

Another(& Best), you can directly obtained the expression for the weight matrix with different lambda and tune for that.

Note: Just treat this problem as many linear regression problem, each with its own lambda.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you have 1300 observations. For some of your outputs, 1295 of 1300 observation have the value zero and 5 obervations have a value $\neq$ 0. Treated independently, you won't create a meaningful regression model for these outputs. Your problem is not with cross-validation, your problem is the extremly unbalanced data set. For now, I would advice to build a regression model only for the outputs where you have sufficent variance in data to do so. 
For all other outputs, maybe you can group them into one binary variable with $0:$ "all values are zero" and thereby generate enough $1$s to solve a classification problem. Or you just need to get more data...